# Rails: Eager loading as_json includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
  render :json => {
    "playlist" => playlist_description,
    "songs" => @playlist.songs.as_json(:include => {:playlist_songs => {:only => [:id, :position]}})
  }
```

The above code results in 1+N queries to the database, one to load playlist_songs for each song.
The playlist is preloaded in @playlist.

This is so slow, how can I optimize?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

My guess: You're not eager-loading the playlist_songs at the moment. You're currently waiting until the as_json call - after which all the songs have been loaded - and then the code has to iterate over every song and fetch the playlist_songs then.

My guess (this is totally untested and may include bugs)

```
@playlist.songs.all(:include => :playlist_songs).as_json(:include => {:playlist_songs => {:only => [:id, :position]}})
```

AFAICT, this should *first* eager load all the songs *and* the playlist_songs... and then render as json.

Answer (score 4):

I would highly recommend integrating with a JSON builder such as [rabl](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl). It will make your life 10x easier moving forward, and is extremely nice to separate the "view" of the JSON representation. I made the switch a couple months ago and haven't looked back.

Within your controller:

```
@playlist = Playlist.where(:id => params[:id]).includes(:playlist_songs)
```

Then the rabl template could be something like this:

```
object @playlist
attribute :description
child :playlist_songs do
  attributes :id, :position
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
render :json => {
  "playlist" => playlist_description,
  "songs" => @playlist.songs.all.as_json(:include => {:playlist_songs => {:only => [:id, :position]}})
}
```

^ guess